# ¿Como puede ejecutar todas las consultas juntas en mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente procedimiento en mariadb el cual se le pasa un numero e imprime la tabla de multiplicar de este:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pa_tabla(numero INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
        WHILE x <= 10 DO
            SELECT CONCAT(numero, ' x ' , x, ' = ',numero*x) AS 'Tabla';
            SET x = x + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END
```

El codigo funciona correctamente, da la siguien salida:

```
+-----------+
| Tabla     |
+-----------+
| 2 x 0 = 0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,001 sec)

+-----------+
| Tabla     |
+-----------+
| 2 x 1 = 2 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,001 sec)

+-----------+
| Tabla     |
+-----------+
| 2 x 2 = 4 |
+-----------+
```

Entonces me gustaria que la salida que de sea algo asi:

```
+-----------+
| Tabla     |
+-----------+
| 2 x 0 = 0 |
| 2 x 1 = 2 |
| 2 x 2 = 4 |
+-----------+
```

En lugar de la salida que me esta dando ahora mismo, he estado buscando informacion y no encuentro si alguien conoce como hacerlo lo agradeceria muchas gracias de antemano;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar **tablas temporales**, las cuales una vez cerrada la conexión a la base de datos se borrarán automáticamente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pa_tabla(numero INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Multiplicaciones;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Multiplicaciones
    (
        resultado LONGTEXT
    );

    WHILE x <= 10 DO
       insert into Multiplicaciones(resultado) 
       values (SELECT CONCAT(numero, ' x ' , x, ' = ',numero * x));

       SET x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;

    select resultado as 'Tabla' 
    from Multiplicaciones;
END
```

Basándome en lo que ya tienes hecho, lo que haces aquá es: si la tabla ya existe la borras, posteriormente la vuelves a crear, después insertas las multiplicaciones en tu **tabla temporal** y finalmente después de salir del **ciclo while** ejecutas un **comando select** para mostrar los registros de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear una consulta utilizando `UNION`. La idea sería:

```
SELECT "2 x 0 = 0"
UNION SELECT "2 x 1 = 1"
UNION ...
```

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE pa_tabla(numero INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
        SET @q = '';
        WHILE x <= 10 DO
            SET @q = CONCAT(@q, "SELECT '", numero, " x ", x, ' = ', numero * x, "' AS 'Tabla'", IF(x=10, '', ' UNION '));
            SET x = x + 1;
        END WHILE;

        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    END
```

```
call pa_tabla(1)
```

| Tabla |
| --- |
| 1 x 0 = 0 |
| 1 x 1 = 1 |
| 1 x 2 = 2 |
| 1 x 3 = 3 |
| 1 x 4 = 4 |
| 1 x 5 = 5 |
| 1 x 6 = 6 |
| 1 x 7 = 7 |
| 1 x 8 = 8 |
| 1 x 9 = 9 |
| 1 x 10 = 10 |

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/gmIFrV8z)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ha servido mucho, no conocia la sentencia de union, investigare mas sobre ella, me ha gustado mucho y me ha sido muy util

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ir generando un consecutivo con una variable y valerte de una tabla del diccionario de datos que tenga suficientes registros.

Por ejemplo, la tabla INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, suele tener más de mil registros en una base de datos cualquiera.

El query del ejemplo siguiente produce la tabla del 4:

```
SET @row := 0;

select tabla 
from (SELECT concat(4, ' x ' , @row, ' = ', 4 * @row) tabla, @row := @row + 1 as row
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, (SELECT @row := 0) r
       where @row <= 10) q1
;
```

| tabla |
| --- |
| 4 x 0 = 0 |
| 4 x 1 = 4 |
| 4 x 2 = 8 |
| 4 x 3 = 12 |
| 4 x 4 = 16 |
| 4 x 5 = 20 |
| 4 x 6 = 24 |
| 4 x 7 = 28 |
| 4 x 8 = 32 |
| 4 x 9 = 36 |
| 4 x 10 = 40 |

---

[Puedes probarlo en DB Fiddle](https://https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jb3eT4KREMTawQLAZqrPKi/0/)

Comment: Muy agradecido con tu respuesta, no conocia las tablas de diccionarios de datos, la verdad que son muy utiles porque ahorras crear tablas temporales, investigare sobre como añadirlo a mi codigo y te comento como quedo

Comment: Adaptar la consulta para que esté dentro de tu SP debiera resultar sencillo, si se complica, siempre puedes encontrar ayuda por aquí, Un saludo.